# Is there a design pattern for Android that defines how multiple Activites should access a single Service?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I am developing an Android data entry app that saves the entered data to a file. A `Service` (let's call it `FileIOService`) is launched using the filename, and loads and saves data that is passed to it from each `Activity` that the user accesses.

I am trying to make the whole app as robust as possible, and at the moment I feel I need to pay particular attention to the interaction between each `Activity` and the `Service`. Here are the issues I can see:

- If the `Service` is killed by the system, it needs to restart and open the file that it had open: I can handle this by using `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`.
- If an `Activity` is destroyed, for instance by an orientation change, it needs to reconnect to the `Service`.

The thing is, once the Activity launches the Service, there's a while before the Service finishes opening the file and becomes ready for I/O requests. To address this, in my Activity, I have both:

- an inner class subclassing ServiceConnection, with its `onServiceConnected()` method completed
- a private reference to an anonymous inner subclass of BroadcastReceiver, with its `handleMessage()` method completed. This gets called when the Service sends out a broadcast to indicate it's finished opening its file.

Both of these methods then call a `setUpActivity()` method that pulls data from the `Service`. This is where it starts to get ugly. Because `onServiceConnected()` may run before the file is ready for I/O, and `handleMessage()` might be called while the `Service` is not bound to the `Activity`, I have to make both `handleMessage()` and `onServiceConnected()` set boolean flags that can later be checked in `setUpActivity()`, like this:

```
if ((fileLoaded && serviceConnected))
{
    //access the file data
}
```

As I said, this feels ugly and awkward, and relies on setting extra boolean variables.

There's another problem - if my `Activity` launches an external `Activity`, like the Camera app, upon returning to my app the `Service` and `Activity` may both have been destroyed (especially with an orientation change) and the app crashes.

My feeling is that I may be missing some overall pattern that would define how each `Activity` should relate to the `Service`, and vice versa, while remaining robust and able to cope with unexpected terminations/restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore the fact that I am skeptical that this is a valid use case for a service (a service whose existence is simply to read and write files?).

> If the Service is killed by the system, it needs to restart and open the file that it had open: I can handle this by using START_REDELIVER_INTENT.

The service is not "killed by the system". The *process* is killed by the system. This will eradicate your activities as well as your service.

The one possible exception to this is if the user manually stops the service (and *only* the service) from Settings, in which case I have no clue what the expected behavior would be. This should be fairly uncommon nowadays, particularly for an app that the user had just been using. Users will be more inclined to use a task manager, such as swiping your app off the recent-tasks list, which will get rid of the entire process, not just the service.

> If an Activity is destroyed, for instance by an orientation change, it needs to reconnect to the Service.

Not necessarily:

- Bind using the `Application` context (`getApplicationContext()`) instead of from the `Activity` directly
- Use a retained fragment to maintain the binding across the configuration change

> My feeling is that I may be missing some overall pattern that would define how each Activity should relate to the Service, and vice versa, while remaining robust and able to cope with unexpected terminations/restarts.

This is one of the many reasons why I try to avoid the binding pattern altogether. Use a service for processing commands, sent via `startService()`, with results (if any) delivered by `LocalBroadcastManager`, or Otto, or greenrobot's EventBus, or a "real" broadcast `Intent`, or maybe a `Messenger`. Particularly when the service is an `IntentService`, the service nicely cleans up after itself when there is no more work to be done.

Comment: Thanks. I'm open to suggestions, so by all means suggest alternatives (I presume `LocalBroadcastManager` is one) to binding to a `Service`, or indeed using a `Service` at all. My reason for using a `Service` is to handle all file I/O, the methods for which I would otherwise have to replicate in each `Activity`.

Comment: @Spinner: "My reason for using a Service is to handle all file I/O, the methods for which I would otherwise have to replicate in each Activity" -- that is unwise. There are many patterns in Java for code reuse that do not involve creating a `Service`, in large part because there is no such concept as a "service" in Java, and Java has been around for 15+ years. Use inheritance, or composition, or static utility methods, etc.